# django is installed but still django-admin.py command not found

Tags: python, django, path

I was running this command:

```
PYTHONPATH=/opt/graphite/webapp django-admin.py migrate --settings=graphite.settings
```

...but it is showing this error:

```
-sh: django-admin.py: command not found
```

django directory is present in `/usr/local/bin`.

What can be the reasons?

Comment: There is no valid reason to have a `django` folder under `/usr/local/bin`. How did you install Django ?

Comment: i installed using pip3

Answer (score 0):

It should be **django-admin** only not django-admin.py

and if you are using Ubantu then run:

1. python manage.py makemigrations
2. python manage.py migrate
3. python manage.py runserver